# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hadoop, and trying to run some join queries on Hive.
I created two tables (table1 and table2). I executed a Join query but getting the following error message:

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask`

However, when I run this query in the Hive UI, the query gets executed, and I get correct results. Can some one help here in explaining what may be wrong?

Comment: Hive doesn't have a definitive "UI". Where are you querying from?

Comment: I am running it through Hive Editor at http://quickstart.cloudera:8888

Comment: That is called Hue... So, where are you running the query when you get the error? `hive` command is deprecated

Comment: Yes, it's Hue. I am running the query in the Terminal. The normal SQL commands are running fine, except the Join query, after which I get this error:      'hive> select t1.Id,t1.Name,t2.Id,t2.Name from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
Query ID = root_20170926212222_d79b2469-efc1-49db-a2d5-e68a5e1dca87
Total jobs = 1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask'

However, in the Hue editor, the query runs just fine.

Comment: Hue runs queries by HiveServer2. You are bypassing that using the Hive CLI. https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/

Answer (score 13):

I just added the following before running my query and it worked.

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

Comment: This was brilliant. It worked fine for me :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Just put this command before Query:

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

It definitely works!

Comment: Explcanation please... Not going to tweek the config only on three lines of "explanation".

Comment: Some background on the `hive.auto.convert.join` setting itself at https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/engines/hive/hive-mapjoin-options.html, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization#LanguageManualJoinOptimization-PriorSupportforMAPJOIN, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the issue on Cloudera Quick Start VM - 5.12, which was resolved by executing below statement on hive prompt:

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

I hope that below information will be more useful:

**Step-1:** Importing all tables from retail_db database of MySQL

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
--connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db \
--username retail_dba \
--password cloudera \
--num-mappers 1 \
--warehouse-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text \
--as-textfile
```

**Step-2:** Creation of database called retail_db and required tables in Hive

```
create database retail_db;
use retail_db;

create external table categories(
  category_id int,
  category_department_id int,
  category_name string)
row format delimited 
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/categories';

create external table customers(
  customer_id int,
  customer_fname string,
  customer_lname string,
  customer_email string,
  customer_password string,
  customer_street string,
  customer_city string,
  customer_state string,
  customer_zipcode string)
row format delimited 
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/customers';

create external table departments(
  department_id int,
  department_name string)
row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/departments';

create external table order_items(
  order_item_id int,
  order_item_order_id int,
  order_item_product_id int,
  order_item_quantity int,
  order_item_subtotal float,
  order_item_product_price float)
row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/order_items';

create external table orders(
  order_id int,
  order_date string,
  order_customer_id int,
  order_status string)
row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/orders';

create external table products(
  product_id int,
  product_category_id int,
  product_name string,
  product_description string,
  product_price float,
  product_image string)
row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cloudera/sqoop/import-all-tables-text/products';
```

**Step-3:** Execute JOIN query

```
SET hive.cli.print.current.db=true;

select o.order_date, sum(oi.order_item_subtotal)
from orders o join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id)
group by o.order_date 
limit 10;
```

***Above query was giving below issue:***

Query ID = cloudera_20171029182323_6eedd682-256b-466c-b2e5-58ea100715fb
Total jobs = 1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

**Step-4:** Above issue was resolved by executing below statement on HIVE prompt:

```
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

**Step-5:** Query Result

```
select o.order_date, sum(oi.order_item_subtotal)
from orders o join order_items oi on (o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id)
group by o.order_date 
limit 10;

Query ID = cloudera_20171029182525_cfc70553-89d2-4c61-8a14-4bbeecadb3cf
Total jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1509278183296_0005, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1509278183296_0005/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1509278183296_0005
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 1
2017-10-29 18:25:19,861 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-10-29 18:25:26,181 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.72 sec
2017-10-29 18:25:27,240 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 5.42 sec
2017-10-29 18:25:32,479 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 8.01 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 8 seconds 10 msec
Ended Job = job_1509278183296_0005
Launching Job 2 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1509278183296_0006, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1509278183296_0006/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1509278183296_0006
Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2017-10-29 18:25:38,676 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-10-29 18:25:43,925 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 0.85 sec
2017-10-29 18:25:49,142 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2.13 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 130 msec
Ended Job = job_1509278183296_0006
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 8.01 sec   HDFS Read: 8422614 HDFS Write: 17364 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-2: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.13 sec   HDFS Read: 22571 HDFS Write: 407 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 10 seconds 140 msec
OK
2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   68153.83132743835
2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   136520.17266082764
2013-07-27 00:00:00.0   101074.34193611145
2013-07-28 00:00:00.0   87123.08192253113
2013-07-29 00:00:00.0   137287.09244918823
2013-07-30 00:00:00.0   102745.62186431885
2013-07-31 00:00:00.0   131878.06256484985
2013-08-01 00:00:00.0   129001.62241744995
2013-08-02 00:00:00.0   109347.00200462341
2013-08-03 00:00:00.0   95266.89186286926
Time taken: 35.721 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the AuthMech parameter on connection

i have set it to 2 and defined the Username

that solved my problem on ctas

Regards, 
Okan

Answer (score 0):

In my case, add parameter `configuration` for `execute` will solve this problem.
This problem caused by the conflict of write access.
You should use the `configuration` to make sure you have the write access.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the issue of not setting the queue, so i did following :

**set mapred.job.queue.name=**Queue-Name

this has solved my problem. Hope this will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

while using the hue interface faced the same issue,
below is the answer
Create a /user/admin in hdfs and change permissions for it by using the following commands:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-163 ~]# su - hdfs

[hdfs@ip-10-0-0-163 ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/admin

[hdfs@ip-10-0-0-163 ~]$ hadoop fs -chown admin /user/admin

[hdfs@ip-10-0-0-163 ~]$ exit
```